# I am getting 401 unauthorized response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, single-page-application

```
getThingsApi() {
    let uri = 'https://testapiserver/api/things/';
    let req = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Basic cC5qYWltdXJ1Z2FuLm1jYUBnbWFpbC5jb206MTIzNDU2',
        }
    };
    console.log('InputRequest::' + JSON.stringify(req));
    fetch(uri, req)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            console.log('ResponseAxis::' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error::" + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
}
```

This code it's running fine on codesandbox.io. But It's not working on react native app.

Note: I changed URI just to post an answer!

Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check your Authorization token , mistake in your token

Comment: Basic cC5qYWltdXJ1Z2FuLm1jYUBnbWFpbC5jb206MTIzNDU2 => it was dynamic token which i was using..its constant .

Comment: Try the code as normal javascript code and check the result , if you got 401 as an error does mean you have an issue with your token

Comment: i tried , there i am getting response 200..no issue with that.

Comment: could you please anyone tell the answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally noticed problem , that was when we were sending header request via react native fetch request 'Authorization' key was sending as case small 'authorization' of final packet to server. So it is better to handle the request on server side. We did that and finally it was resolved.